# switching 3A/5V with an optocoupler

Tags: usb, opto-isolator, switching

I am planning to switch the 5V line to a USB load.

I have being going around different suppliers looking for an optocoupler that can handle 3A at 5V. I have seen a few, but upon looking at the datasheet (e.g., [FOD3182](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FO/FOD3182.pdf)), they mentioned that the operating voltage should be at 15 to 30V.

If there aren't any such optocouplers, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Please see the Help Center for rules about shopping questions. Your question will be closed if it remains in its current form. You need to change it to a _design_ question. You also omitted to link to the device datasheet.

Answer (score 3):

If there aren't any such optocouplers, just build your own:

[image: optocoupler switches MOSFET]

The actual optocoupler needs to pass very little current because it controls only the gate of the MOSFET.

Choose a logic-level MOSFET that switches on completely at V<sub>GS</sub>=−5V, and has a low enough R<sub>DS(on)</sub> for your application.

In this circuit, the optocoupler activates the switch. To invert the logic, exchange IC1 and R1.

Answer (score 2):

An optocoupler than can handle that load exists, but it has a different name: "solid-state-relay"

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4n35 with N mos as in this diagram:
http://www.alcs.ch/webdata/arduino/dimmer/dimmer_v1.png

What will be the load ? Because you may need extra diode  for motor load for exemple